# Strange behavior observed in inheritence

Tags: java, inheritance

I have an interface, **IfcBase** which is implemented by another class **Base**. This class is further extended by a second class **SubBase**. Further SubBase class implements another interface **IfcNew**. Both these interfaces have a method declared that has the same signature. Now SubBase does not define the method from IfcNew. I now create an instance of SubBase and assign it to the reference type IfcNew. I then invoke the lone method and get an output. The method from IfcBase was executed in this case. I believe this should not be allowed at some stage, either during compilation or execution. I fail to understand the behavior and solicit help. The source is below. Thanks a lot!

```
public interface IfcBase
{
    public void printString();
}

public class Base implements IfcBase
{
    public void printString()
    {
        System.out.println("Base Class");
    }
}

public interface IfcNew
{
    public void printString();
}

public class SubBase extends Base implements IfcNew
{
    //
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        IfcNew i = new SubBase(); 
        i.printString();  //Output:Base Class
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only reasonable. It's declared as a type of `IfcNew`. How else should it work? What are your expectations?

Comment: Interfaces just want you to implement the methods. They don't care how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how inheritance works in Java.

You have a method called `public void printString()` implemented in `Base`, from which you extend `SubBase`. As a result this implementation will be implicitly available in this class.

For the `implements IfcNew` part in the `SubBase` declaration, compiler will only check to see if `SubBase` has a method implemented which has the same signature as `public void printString()`. Since it implicitly inherits this implementation from `Base`, it has nothing to complain about.

This behavior can be easily understood if you look at it from OO design point of view. Please take a look at [this article](https://sayemdb.wordpress.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-design-pattern/) which I wrote few years ago. Look under the section called *Method signature, Object Interface, Types, Subtypes and Supertypes*. By the definition of `subtype` that is provided there, `SubBase` is already a subtype of `IfcNew`, so compiler has no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks Sayem but the point here is that the reference type is of the second interface the method of which is not defined. On this reference I am invoking a method but the one defined by the first interface gets executed.

Comment: @user3895747: Check the third paragraph of the answer. I hope it clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Thanks Sayem and Mena for your responses. It clarifies the doubt but I still have this lingering uneasiness. Shouldn't JVM call "the method" specific to the reference. Or shouldn't the compiler not complain about this. Anyway, I'll take the behavior as is. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @user3895747: No, JVM does not associate "the method" specific to the reference. All it does is check to see if the implementing class has implemented methods which match the signature of the methods defined in the interface. If it finds such implementation, it's happy.

Comment: So that explains! Thanks everyone for your views. God bless!

Comment: @user3895747: I have added a link to one of my articles about subtyping and what it means in OO design. You can read that for further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct behavior of inheritance in Java.

There is no warning when implementing multiple interfaces with same-signature methods, because resolution takes place at runtime.

In this case, your `SubBase` class does not need to implement `printString` as its parent does, even if it isn't the "same" `printString`: the identical signature allows resolution at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious and not strange. This is because the method with same signature is already implemented in the base class and when you extend the base class it is automatically inherited. Now when you try to assign the object to IfcNew reference the method implemented is called which is not overriden in subclass, meaning that the base class method is called which actually is the implementation of IfcBase.